# How to Fix Getting Duplicate Entry on Update of Entity JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update an old file entry in my database with a new entity. Essential I save an initial file entity to the DB then update the a new entity with the relevant information saved to the DB(including ID which is the primary key). But when I try to save the new entity I get an `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [md5_UNIQUE]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`. I can see it's not working to which I proved to myself that the information was being copied over correctly in the logs. I am assuming there is something I'm missing as to why it's not updating the information.

Prior to me adding the first save it was working but because of a lack of UNIQUE identifier for the MD5 column it was causing duplicates but I changed that and added an initial save to prevent it from getting so far in that the file is already saved before it's caught by the database. Essentially just a check in the beginning.

This is my abstracthandler:

```
public abstract class AbstractFileResolver {

    @Autowired private FileRepository fileRepository;

    protected abstract File processUpload(MultipartFile file, File entity) throws Exception;
    protected abstract File found(File file);

    public File upload(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(file.getInputStream());
        File found = fileRepository.findOneByMd5(md5);

        if (null != found) return found(found);

        File newFile = null;
        try {
            File f = new File();
            f.setMd5(md5);
            newFile = fileRepository.save(f);
            return processUpload(file, newFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("There was an error processing upload.", e);
            if (newFile != null) fileRepository.delete(newFile);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my implemented handler:

```
public class JpegImageFileResolverImpl extends AbstractFileResolver {

    @Autowired private FileRepository fileRepository;
    @Autowired private ImageMetaData imageMetaData;
    @Autowired private PropertiesBean properties;

    @Override
    protected File processUpload(MultipartFile file, File entity) throws Exception {
        Jpeg model = (Jpeg) imageMetaData.loadImage(file, new Jpeg());
        model.setFilePath(imageMetaData.generateNewFilePath(model));
        java.io.File uploadedFile = new java.io.File(properties.rootDirectory + model.getFilePath());
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(uploadedFile, file.getBytes());
        model.setId(entity.getId()); // setting the import info
        return fileRepository.save(model); // this is the error
    }
}
```

This is my file entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="files")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class File {

    @Id
    @Column(name="file_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id = 0;

    @Column(name="md5")
    private String md5 = "";

    @Column(name="uploaded")
    private Timestamp uploaded;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

This is my Jpeg Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="jpegs")
public class Jpeg extends AbstractImage {

    @Column(name="quality", nullable=false)
    private String quality = "";

    @Column(name="optimized", nullable=false)
    private boolean optimized = false;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

This is my abstract image:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="images")
public class AbstractImage extends File{

    @Column(name="dpi", nullable=false)
    private int dpi = 0;

    // Getter and setter
}
```

The expected result is that when I initially save the table will look something like this:

```
| file_id |               md5              | Timestamp |
|---------|--------------------------------|-----------|
| 1       |033f6535fa99857722f43301e68d8b82| null      |
```

But after all the work has been completed on it, it should look like this when it hits the second save:

```
| file_id |               md5              | Timestamp |
|---------|--------------------------------|-----------|
| 1       |033f6535fa99857722f43301e68d8b82| 2019-01-03|
```

But, like I was saying above, I feel like this just doesn't work or maybe it does and I'm missing something. If I am missing something what am I missing? If it doesn't work how do you suggest I get around the issue?

Comment: _I am trying to update an old file entry in my database with a new entity_ so what is impl for `File found(File file)`? Does _But when I try to save the new entity..._ mean **initial** or **found**  (& updated) entity?

Comment: @pirho `found` is just a workaround. It will grab a `jpeg` object from the repository using the found `file`. If you follow the `processUpload` it takes a new `jpeg` object and loads it with information about the file. Then I copy over the MD5 and file_id then call save on the new jpeg object. However, I'm really just trying to update the file information in the table with the new information, hence copying over the id as trying to update the information on the table.